# Don't know how to return sth in a then of a promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, es6-promise

I am using firebase, where I am using some promises (in a react native app).

I am trying to deploy, but ESLINT is complaining that my then clause does not return anything:

```
admin.auth().getUser(phone)
    .then(userRecord => {
      const code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8999 + 1000))

      twilio.messages.create({
        body: 'Your code is ' + code,
        to: phone,
        from: '+4915735984308'
      }, (err) => {
        if (err) { return res.status(422).send(err) }

        admin.database().ref('users/' + phone)
          .update({code: code, codeValid: true}, () => {
            res.send({success: true})
          })
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(422).send({error: err})
    })
```

The problem is, I don't want to return anything, just write things in the database. I tried the following without success:

```
.then(userRecord => {
      const code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8999 + 1000))

      twilio.messages.create({
        body: 'Your code is ' + code,
        to: phone,
        from: '+4915735984308'
      }, (err) => {
        if (err) { return res.status(422).send(err) }

        admin.database().ref('users/' + phone)
          .update({code: code, codeValid: true}, () => {
            res.send({success: true}, () => {return true})
          })
      }, () => {return true})
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(422).send({error: err}, () => {return true})
    })
```

Can someone help me with this? Where should I write the return statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try returning the last line

```
admin.auth().getUser(phone)
    .then(userRecord => {
      const code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8999 + 1000))

      return twilio.messages.create({
        body: 'Your code is ' + code,
        to: phone,
        from: '+4915735984308'
      }, (err) => {
        if (err) { return res.status(422).send(err) }

        admin.database().ref('users/' + phone)
          .update({code: code, codeValid: true}, () => {
            res.send({success: true})
          })
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(422).send({error: err})
    })
```

Comment: didn't understand what you mean. what is the last lilne? the code that you put is the same as the first one that I posted

Comment: its not.       return twilio.messages.create({

Comment: oh sorry, now. thanks. so i can return another promise right?

Comment: How it works is you return either a value from then or a promise. Since you're not writing an api of some sort, you can just return twilio.messages.create promise

Comment: Yes, returning a promise is expected. The idea is to chain things:
a.then(//return create message).then(message) . ...